# Проблема линкера STM32 + QT Creator

Tags: qt, компоновщик, stm32

Настраиваю связку STM32 + QT Creator QBS + Ubuntu 16 + OpenOCD + st-link.
Собираю и настраиваю по этому [мануалу](http://pavelk.ru/stm32f3-discovery). Причем смотрел кучу мануалов, брал кучу исходных проектов, все проходит нормально ровно до этапа компиляции и линковки.
Всегда одна и та же ошибка:

> "arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: unrecognised emulation mode: fpu=fpv4-sp-d16
>   Supported emulations: armelf"

Тулчейн ARM ставился так:

> sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi

Мой QBS выглядит так:

```
import qbs

Product {
Depends { name : "cpp" }
type: "application"
consoleApplication: true
cpp.positionIndependentCode: false
name: "test_F4_1"
cpp.includePaths : [ 
    "Inc",
    "Drivers/CMSIS/Include",
    "Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include",
    "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc"
    ]

Group {
    name: "linker scripts"
    files: [ "STM32F407VGTx_FLASH.ld", "LIBS.ld" ]
    fileTags: ["linkerscript"]
}
cpp.commonCompilerFlags: [ 
    "-mthumb",
    "-mcpu=cortex-m4",
    "-mfloat-abi=hard",
    "-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16"
    ]
cpp.linkerFlags: [
    "-mthumb",
    "-mcpu=cortex-m4",
    "-mfloat-abi=hard",
    "-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16",
    "--specs=nano.specs",
    "-Xlinker",
    "--gc-sections",
    "-lgcc",
    "-lm",
    "--specs=nosys.specs",
    "-lc"
    ]
cpp.defines: [ "STM32F407xx" ]
cpp.cLanguageVersion: "c99"
cpp.cxxLanguageVersion: "c++11"


Group {
    files: [ 
        "Inc/stm32f4xx_it.h",
        "Inc/stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h",
        "Inc/main.h",
        "Src/stm32f4xx_it.c",
        "Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c",
        "Src/main.c"
        ]
    name: "STM32CubeMX"
}

Group {
    files: [ 
        "Drivers/CMSIS/Include/core_cm4.h"
        ]
    name: "CMSIS.CORE"
}

Group {
    files: [ 
        "Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include/stm32f4xx.h",
        "Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include/system_stm32f4xx.h",
        "Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/system_stm32f4xx.c",
        "startup/startup_stm32f407xx.s"
        ]
    name: "Device.Startup"
}

Group {
    files: [ 
        "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/stm32f4xx_hal.h",
        "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.c"
        ]
    name: "Device.STM32Cube HAL.COMMON"
}

Group {
    files: [
        ]
    name: "Device.STM32Cube HAL.RCC"
}

Group {
    files: [
        ]
    name: "Device.STM32Cube HAL.CORTEX"
}

Group {
    files: [
        ]
    name: "Device.STM32Cube HAL.TIM"
}

Group {
    files: [
        ]
    name: "Device.STM32Cube HAL.DMA"
}

Group {
    files: [
        ]
    name: "Device.STM32Cube HAL.COMMON"
}

Group {
    files: [
        ]
    name: "Device.STM32Cube HAL.PWR"
}

Group {
    files: [
        ]
    name: "Device.STM32Cube HAL.FLASH"
}

Group {
    files: [
        ]
    name: "Device.STM32Cube HAL.GPIO"
}

}
```